# Stack up a array? - Array in Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Because I must minimize my SQL statements I'm forced to load the entire database to a local array. I want to sort the array like this:

```
array(500){
   [489] => array(4){
        [name] => string(9) "From Dust"
        [price] => double(4) "8.99"
        [shop] => int(4) "9507"
        [url] => string(120) "https://de.gamesplanet........"
    }
   [490] => ....
}
```

Does anybody know how I can do that? - I already tried myself, but it doesn't work. My SQL query is not wrong. You can see that because I print the value I get by the query to the console... So there must be somewhere else the error...

Does anybody sees the error?

```
$stmt = $GLOBALS["database"]->query("SELECT id, name, price, shop, url FROM `wp_all_import_xml`");

    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){

        echo $row['id'] . ": " . $row['name'] . "\t" . $row['price'] . "\t" .$row['shop'] . "\t" . $row['url'] . "\n";

        $Globals["productsXML"][$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $Globals["productsXML"][$row['id']]['price'] = $row['price'];
        $Globals["productsXML"][$row['id']]['shop'] = $row['shop'];
        $Globals["productsXML"][$row['id']]['url'] = $row['url'];
    }
```

Comment: `$Globals` is not [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

Comment: And I have another question regarding to this stacked array. If I want to search in this array if there are entries who are matching the url, shop, price and name, what is the best way to check that?

Comment: This question seems unanswered/abandoned.  Is this question resolved? or does it require assistance?  If you no longer have any issues please delete this question.  If you would like help with something, please do not ask with comments, please edit your question.